# Which one has lower latency? HDMI to Type-C or HDMI to HDMI or the same?

Tags: hdmi

I wonder if Android smartphones with HDMI port has advantage versus without if they have USB Type-C. If I have Type-C, I can use Type-C to HDMI adapter.

Comment: I don't believe there exists a smartphone with HDMI? All the phones I know need an adapter. I think you mean to compare MHL with USB-C.

Comment: Is [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+phone+hdmi+port&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiq87jL6abnAhWYyCoKHd9_B8EQ2-cCegQIABAC&oq=android+phone+hdmi+port&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-img.3..33i10.2640.7713..7815...0.0..0.131.1130.1j9......0....1.........0j0i8i30j0i24j30i10.DrlZOwu6qSU&ei=B3AwXurTHZiRqwHf_52IDA&bih=604&biw=412&prmd=ivmn#imgrc=VSOToYQL8RWynM) not HDMI?

Comment: Wow...there's one that exists. But it's 10 years old and Android 2...so people wouldn't use it nowadays. Virtually no name branded phone from the last 5 years have hardware HDMI afaik. It's just too big to fit on a phone.

Comment: If the phone supports output of display signal via USB-C alternative mode (Displayport signals) you should get the lowest latency if you don't convert the signals and connect a monitor via Displayport. For example using an USB-C to USB-C cable and an monitor with USB-C input port. Or an USB-C to Displayport adapter plus matching cable. HDMI signals are always converted and may therefore have a small latency.

Comment: @Robert Thanks, I have LG V20. Is DP Alt mode support is the same as MHL support? I found that my device support MHL but didn't find info if it supports DP Alt Mode. I'm planning to buy [this](https://a.aliexpress.com/_slXNYu). Will everything work on my device?

Comment: @vasik988 No, MHL is the ancient Micro-USB based version of transmitting. It seems that there is also a version that uses the USB-C alt mode but the data is according to the spec different to Displayport via USB-C alt mode. Therefore you need special USB-C MHL converter that output e.g. HDMI: http://www.mhltech.org/usbtype-c.aspx

Comment: What specs are saying that it isn't compatible with my device? I also took a look to [Microsoft Display Dock](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/accessory/hd-500/specifications) and I saw a video in Youtube that can be used with LG G5 and in specs there is nothing about MHL. I think, item from Aliexprees, should function the same like this Display Dock. Do you see any difference?